# С помощью чего сделать HTML документ? asp.net core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

нужно генерировать HTML страницу на сервере по заданным данным, что бы после отправить человеку email с прикреплённой html формой

писать тупо строкой не тем => типа того:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

может есть какие билдеры?  (ASP.NET Core)

(что-то вроде HtmlTextWriter, как в framework)

Comment: Так ASP.NET его сам рендерит. Более конкретно опишите проблему. Есть методы "полуручного" рендеринга как для одного елемента, так и для всей страницы. Но читая вопрос - не понятно в чём у вас трудность. В простейшем случае берёте `Response.Write`  и делайте документ.

Comment: Построитель страницы - т.е. студия?

Comment: Ох, ё-моё... нет слов просто.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно принято делать это в представлениях (view).

Т.е. у вас есть контроллер, который получает данные:

```
public class BookController : Controller
{
    public BookController()
    {
        this.Books = new List<Book>()
        {
            new Book { Id = 1, Title = "книга 1" },
            new Book { Id = 2, Title= "книга 2" },
        };
    }

    public List<Book> Books { get; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllBooks()
    {
        var model = this.Books; // TODO: Read from db
        return this.View(model);
    }
}
```

И есть некоторое представление, в котором отображаются данные нужным способом:

```
@model IEnumerable<Book>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Все книги";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>title</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var book in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@book.Id</td>
                <td>@book.Title</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Вот и всё. Почитайте про подход mvc (model-view-controller), это вам поможет.

При этом повторяющийся код всех страниц (header-footer и т.п.) принято выносить в единый файл _Layout.cshtml (а в контроллере прописывают только саму серёдку страницы).

Начните изучение с какого-нибудь букваря по asp.net, например [этого](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/).

Также, в asp.net core возможен другой подход - Razor Pages. Суть примерно такая же, только сделано немного иначе: у вас есть файл AllBooks.cshtml с разметкой и файл AllBooks.cshtml.cs с управляющим кодом.

Пример файла AllBooks.cshtml.cs:

```
public class GetAllBooksModel : PageModel
{
    public GetAllBooksModel()
    {
        this.Books = new List<Book>()
        {
            new Book { Id = 1, Title = "книга 1" },
            new Book { Id = 2, Title= "книга 2" },
        };
    }

    public List<Book> Books { get; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

И практически такой же файл AllBooks.cshtml:

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.GetAllBooksModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Все книги";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>title</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var book in Model.Books)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@book.Id</td>
                <td>@book.Title</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(Здесь так же генерируется только сердевина страницы, а остальная обвязка записана в _Layout)

А вот так может выглядеть /View/Shared/_Layout.cshtml (обратите внимание на директиву, которая подключает генерацию содержимого страницы, которое вы пишете в контроллерах или razor pages):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApp1</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6">
                    <p>&copy; 2018 - WebApp1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать Razor отдельно от AST.NET MVC, но придется написать ~50 строк, чтобы его настроить. Посмотрите сниипет в ответе на похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247080/using-razor-outside-of-mvc-in-net-core/47756437#47756437